# Laravel How to get an id from another table without a 1 to 1 relation

Tags: php, laravel

So i have a `Registrations` and a `Gender` table. And i want to get the `id` from Gender and use it in the `RegistrationController`. The Registration doesn't have a `gender_id`, but it does have a `category_id`, and the `Category` table has a `gender_id`. But i don't want to use the `gender_id` in the Categories because this check I'm making is for those `gender_ids` in the Categories.

**This is what i have right now in the `RegistrationController`:**

```
$gender = Gender::all();
$gender_id = $gender->gen_id;
dd($gender_id);
```

here it says '`gen_id`' doesn't exist.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats the structure of you `gender`  table?

Comment: try `Gender::first();` not `Gender::all();`

Comment: the `Gender` table has a gen_id and a gen_name

Comment: And i need to get all the gen_ids, not only the first one

Answer (score 2):

Use pluck `method` for get all `gen_ids`

```
$gen_ids = Gender::pluck('gen_id')->toArray();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($gen_ids);
exit;
```

It'll give you all gender id in array.

Comment: select the answer if helped.

Answer (score 1):

`Gender::all();` => fetch all the rows from table. So it's not helped you to find exact rows. so you have two different way to find, the first is `Gender::first()` => it's get the first of the row from table and `Gender::find($id)` => you can find the exact record.

Comment: when i try `Gender::find($id)` it says `Undefined variable: id`